# xmlhttprequest meaning of headers definition

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I should write a journal when I do changes in my code to make it work, sometimes, in a rush, I just put it to work without knowing exactly why.

I did change a setRequestHeader of a xmlhttprequest from "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" to "application/octet-stream", for some reason, but later, when trying to reuse the code to send some vars by POST to a php, it didn't work. After a while examining the case, I did change it back and the vars finally reach it's destination!

So what means each one of this headers, how it changes the way data is exchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the content-type for the standard way of encoding form data (which is also used in query strings).

`application/octet-stream` is the content-type for "some bytes of date, in no particular format" (often it is used for "I don't know what this is" and sometimes for "I don't want the browser to know what this is" when `Content-Disposition` should be used instead).

The header doesn't change how the data is exchanged, it just informs the recipient of what format the data is in.

If PHP is told the data is in a format that it doesn't know how to parse then it won't parse it and populate `$_POST` and friends.

Comment: I think this clarify a lot. I got some troubles when loading/sending xml that browser decide to "take a look", so I was encoding manually the data, maybe octet-stream is an option to try. And the first one probably will be the usual choice to send forms. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`x-www-form-urlencoded` means it escapes some special characters and make the whole datapackage (form) one single string.
`octet-stream` i never seen this format but my raw guess is that its a stream of 8 bit chunks of data.

Comment: Yes, it seams a basic stream of data.